# Node.js require.context() from subdirectory

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

Wondering if it is possible within node to require context for a folder which is higher in the folder structure e.g. would it be possible to get to the Parent2 dir from child 1 (see file structure below) with code like

```
require.context('../Parent2', true)
```

For a structure like

```
Root

-Parent1

--child1

-Parent2
```

Comment: Maybe this could help you out https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-context

Comment: aitäh Hendry !!!